# Waiting for the recruiter's response took more than 4 months

Tags: interviewing

I have done a lot interviews with my dream company, and in the end they told me that I was the first to go this far and I will need to wait for some time so they can do other interviews and be sure about the profile that they will recruit.

Now, It's been more than 4 months since our last interview:

- After a month I asked them if there are any news, they said that nothing happened yet and I am very much kept in mind
- After the second month I asked them again and they told me that nothing happened yet
- And after the third month they told me that the interview process was delayed because of the manager's schedule

I don't know if I should ask again?  Or should I forget about them because they seem not going further with this job?

Comment: Perhaps this would be a better duplicate: [How often should I contact a company when they keep telling me my application is "under consideration"?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1878)

Answer (score 6):

By all means ask again.

But don't let this prevent you from continuing to explore other opportunities.  Sometimes things change, projects don't take off, budgeting strategies change - there's many reasons why recruitment drives don't lift off.

If you're getting responses back, keep at them.  But don't for a second count on this job happening.

Answer (score 3):

> Or should I forget about them because they seem not going further with
>   this job?

**Forget about this an move on.**

You have had an interview with them already, they did not all of the sudden forget how to contact you.  Sadly it appears they have moved on, and you should too.

Feel free however to apply to any **new** positions that may come up that your interested in **and** qualified for, but this one is done.

Answer (score 2):

If the manager is too busy for an interview in a 3 month period then this is a low to no priority.  They are not even sure about the profile they will recruit.

Not likely this will close but no harm in continuing to ask monthly.

You should actively look for other opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

The person who interviewed you didn't have the power to hire you or they didn't want too.

The person you are talking too to find out what happen doesn't have the power to change that.

Since this is your *dream company* you shouldn't give up, but find a different point of entry. Network with people you know and try to connect with a person inside the company who has the power to hire you.

But, don't just wait or ignore other opportunities elsewhere.